# What is the technology behind Azure Event Grid?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

What is the underlying technology used to build Azure Event Grid and where can I find its source code? I searched the Azure Github account and could only find an Event Grid emulator. Does AEG build on a different project, similar to how Azure WebJobs are used as the foundation for other offerings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is built on Service Fabric. If you are looking for SDK samples, you can start here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples

The code for the actual service is not available.